# MYSQL CURSOR use unicode

Tags: mysql

I can select it well。

But，when I use `FETCH dept_csr INTO l_id,l_code1,l_code2;`

and I call the proc， it show  `???`  for `管爺`

so， how can I fix this proc to show Chinese correcly.

```
BEGIN

  DECLARE l_id          INT;
  DECLARE l_code1      CHAR(8);
  DECLARE l_code2      CHAR(2);
  DECLARE l_count      INT;
  DECLARE no_more_maps INT;


  DECLARE dept_csr CURSOR FOR
       select cID,cName,cSex from students;


  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_maps=1;


  SET no_more_maps=0;


  OPEN dept_csr;
        dept_loop:REPEAT         
           FETCH dept_csr INTO l_id,l_code1,l_code2;
           IF no_more_maps=0 THEN
                SET l_count=l_count+1;
                select l_id,l_code1,l_code2;
           END IF;
        UNTIL no_more_maps
        END REPEAT dept_loop;
        CLOSE dept_csr;
        SET no_more_maps=0;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  DECLARE l_code1      CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET utf8;
  DECLARE l_code2      CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: Dear eggyal：Thx for your answer，it's OK now!